# Jfrog cli docker image is not persistent

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

While running JFrog CLI as a docker container via using `docker run releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/jfrog-cli-full-v2-jf jf -v`
The container get exited, hence I am not able to configure.

Answer (score 2):

JFrog CLI stores its configuration inside its home directory, named .jfrog on the local system.
By default, the .jfrog directory is located under the user home directory. You have the option of changing the home directory location by setting the `JFROG_CLI_HOME_DIR` environment variable.

So if you'd like JFrog CLI to access the home directory from inside a container, you'll need to mount the container's JFrog CLI home directory to the directory on the host machine. You can do this using docker's volume feature, by adding the -v option to the command as follows:

```
docker run -v ~/.jfrog:/home/frogger/.jfrog releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/jfrog-cli-full-v2-jf jf c show
```

In the above command, we're mapping the host machine's `~/.jfrog` directory to the container's `/home/frogger/.jfrog` directory. The `releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/jfrog-cli-full-v2-jf` container's user home is `/home/frogger`.